# Keeping track of history of commands of multiple sessions of ksh

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, bash

I am using multiple sessions of ksh on a linux machine. On one terminal when I do history, I only see history of commands typed on that terminal. 
When I log out all sessions, I want to make sure that history of commands typed on all the terminal get appended on one file say .bash_history. Is it possible?

Even when I don't log out, are all these commands dynamically get appended to this history file?

I am wary of losing my commands like when someone helps me do something, I want to make sure that I can refer to that command later on.

How do I set the size of .bash_history file

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, what is the name of history file in ksh shell?

Comment: Are you wanting to intermingle Bash and ksh history? That seems to be part of what you're asking.

Comment: No Dennis, I just want history of ksh. This is what I am using these days. Recalled the name .bash_history from my old days with bash..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HISTSIZE will set the size of your history, default is 512; HISTFILE should be set to the name of your history file, default is ~/.sh_history.

I suppose you could set HISTFILE to ~/.bash_history, but that might be confusing later on.

From what I can see of the docs on ksh, it should be merging your history from multiple invocations.  Try opening three separate sessions and issuing a distinct different command on each then logging out.  Open a new instance of your term and view your history file - are they all there?

Tested out ok under ksh on Mac OS X